# Can I change the lockup period of a deployed smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I want to create a smart contract that locks tokens for a certain amount of time, however, I want the ability for this time period to be changed while the tokens are still locked up.

For example: the tokens are locked for 12 months initially, but governance votes to change that period to 8 months after the tokens have already been locked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have implemented the functionality to change the lockup period.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint256 lockupPeriod = 12;
    address admin = address(0x123);

    function setLockupPeriod(uint256 _lockupPeriod) external {
        // reverts if this function is executed by anyone else except for the `admin`
        // or you can implement the voting governance requirement instead of one admin
        require(msg.sender == admin, 'Not authorized');
        lockupPeriod = _lockupPeriod;
    }
}
```

But after you deploy a smart contract, it's immutable by design. So you can't change something that haven't been designed to be changeable. *(Generally speaking. There are few exceptions to this rule such as the "upgradable proxy" pattern or "selfdestruct & create2".)*